# extjs4: how to submit the same form data twice

Tags: javascript, forms, servlets, extjs, extjs4

I have an input form with 2 buttons, submit and save. Initially both buttons will be disabled. Once,the user enters the data, the submit button will be enabled and he submits the form,which goes to the servlet for validating(By validating,I mean I send the userID and password to check if it is existing in the database)

Here is my handler for submit button:

```
validateForm: function(button){
        console.log('Validatingform');
        var formData=button.up('form').getForm();
        if(formData.isValid()){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url : 'MyServlet',
                params : {
                    inputData:Ext.encode(formData.getValues()),
                    validate:"valid"
                },
                scope : this,
                success : this.onValid,
                failure : this.onInvalid
            });
        }
    },

onValid: function(response,button){
        console.log("Valid");
        //on valid-enable save button,disable submit button
        Ext.getCmp('myFormSubmit').setDisabled(true);
        Ext.getCmp('myFormSave').enable();

    },
```

After checking for validation. In the OnValid method, I enable the save button and click on save button to save the form data now.

But since,the form was already submitted,the input to my servlet is **"null"**.

I am not sure on how to hold this form data entered by the user for multiple submits. Can anyone please guide me on solving this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you disabling the form items after user hits "submit" button?

Comment: No..I just disable the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like saving the data on the button/form be suitable? Probably not the best idea but it's a thought

```
    validateForm: function(button){
    console.log('Validatingform');
    var formData=button.up('form').getForm();
    if(formData.isValid()){
        //
        if (!button.savedData){
            button.savedData = formdata;    
        }

        //
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : 'MyServlet',
            params : {
                inputData:Ext.encode(formData.getValues()),
                validate:"valid"
            },
            scope : this,
            success : this.onValid,
            failure : this.onInvalid
        });
    }
},

onValid: function(response,button){
    console.log("Valid");
    var submitBtn = Ext.getCmp('myFormSubmit');
//on valid-enable save button,disable submit button
    submitBtn.setDisabled(true);
    Ext.getCmp('myFormSave').enable();
    if (submitBtn && submitBtn.savedData){
        formdata = submitBtn.savedData;
        delete submitBtn.savedData;
   }
//
},

onInvalid: function(response,button){
    var submitBtn = Ext.getCmp('myFormSubmit');
    if (submitBtn && submitBtn.savedData){
        formdata = submitBtn.savedData;
        delete submitBtn.savedData;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Sure I will try. If you could tell about your idea more clearly..it will be very helpful

Comment: The code i posted checks to see if the submit button has any data saved, and if not, saves the formdata in the property savedData of the button (this is not a native property, but Ext allows you to add these properties); then, when the onValid function is called, it gets the submit button reference and checks to see if this button has a property called savedData. If so, it will create a new var called formData from this property, and this var can be used for a new submit,etc. After this, it deleted the property from the button, to allow for new submits with different information.

Comment: onInvalid also clears this property, just to make sure that there is no old data in the flow.

Comment: Okay thank u so much..I got it.I am going to try it now